# Paypal integration questions

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have some code that i wrote many years ago to integrate Paypal within my site. So a user adds multiple products to their cart and then checks out which then automatically takes the user to the paypal site.
I decided to revisit it today and created the following HTML

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail-facilitator@myDomain.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product 1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://XX/paypal/completed.aspx"/>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://XX/paypal/Cancel.aspx"/>
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://XX/paypal/MyShop"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://XX/paypal/MyShop/checkout.aspx"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB"/>
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://XX/paypal/shop.gif"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="ZZZ1234567890"/>
<script type="text/javascript">document.myForm.submit();</script></form>
```

***This came up with an error "Error Detected Your shopping cart is empty".***

Logged into my sandbox account and no error listed to determine what ive done wrong.
Googled around  which suggested to change `_cart` to `_xclick` - which resolved the issue, however when i read the documentation at

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

1. I dont understand why _cart didnt work? Is there a more appropriate way to do this or _xclick fine with my site setup as described above?
2. For multiple items i was looping the item_name and amount and adding each value, but this doesnt work the way i expected i.e. I've seen sites where they display each product, quantity and amount for each product in the cart and then total - where did i go wrong?
3. Finally once a transaction is complete i have set up the IPN value to send the details to my site..... Do i need the site to be using https in order for this to work or would http work?

I tried searching for these answers but some are quite dated or using 3rd part components.

Answer (score 1):

Please make below changes to your HTML codes to make your form work again.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product 1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"/>
```

↓↓

```html
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product 1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="500.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>
```